# How can I remove leap year days from time attribute in R?

Tags: r, time

I am not familiar in R hence I need a help. I have a 30 yearly dataset from netCDF in dimensions: time latitude, longitude

```
Data: num [1:10958, 1:29, 1:57] 0.595 5.751 ....
..- attr(*,"dimensions") = chr[1:3] "time" "lat" "lon"
```

where the time is:

```
Dates : List of 2
..$start: chr [1:10958] “1971-01-01 12:00:00 GTM” “1971-01-02 12:00:00 GTM” …
..$end: chr [1:10958] “1971-01-01 12:00:00 GTM” “1971-01-02 12:00:00 GTM” …
```

I removed the data in 29th of February (leap year data) by the following way:

```
datesList1 <- as.POSIXct(pred$Dates$start, tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
 yearList1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(datesList1), "[-]"))
  dayListPred <- array(data = c(as.numeric(yearList1[seq(2,length(yearList1),3)]),as.numeric(yearList1[seq(3,length(yearList1),3)])), dim = c(length(datesList1),2))
      leap_p <- array(0,c(nrow(dayListPred),1))
      k_p <- which(dayListPred[,1]==2 & dayListPred[,2]==29)
      leap_p[k_p] <- 1
      leap_p <- which(leap_p ==0)
      pred$Data <- pred$Data[leap_p,,]
```

I would like to redefine `pred$Data` in the new time dimension so I need to remove the leap year days from the original dates attribute. Could someone suggest me a solution?